# How can we update some nodes in an xml column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below in an xml column of a table. How can I write a query that replaces only part of the value for all  ? The text REPLACE will be replaced with another value.

```
<Root>
    <Response xmlns:ns1="urn:names:tc:legalxml-message1:schema:xsd:Message-4.0">
        <Message xmlns:ns2="urn:names:tc:legalxml-message2:schema:xsd:Types-4.0">
            <Response1>
                <ns1:Name>REPLACE name1</Name>
            </Response1>

            <Response2>
                <ns1:Name>REPLACE name2</Name>
            </Response2>

            <Response3>
                <ns1:Name>REPLACE name3</Name>
            </Response3>

            <Response4>
                <ns1:Name>REPLACE name4</Name>
            </Response4>
        </Message>
    </Response>
</Root>
```

I tried the below query and received an error message.

XQuery [r.x.modify()]: The target of 'replace value of' must be a non-metadata attribute or an element with simple typed content, found 'element(Name,xdt:untyped) ?'

I was following this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28601.t-sql-tips-search-and-replace-string-from-multiple-nodes-within-a-xml-document.aspx).

```
declare @SearchString varchar(100),@ReplaceString varchar(100)

SELECT @SearchString = 'REPLACE',@ReplaceString = 'NEWVALUE'

UPDATE r
SET x.modify('replace value of (/Root/Response/Message/Response1/Name)[1] with sql:column("y")')
FROM (SELECT xmlColumn,REPLACE(t.u.value('Name[1]','varchar(100)'),@SearchString,@ReplaceString) as y
FROM tblMessage
CROSS APPLY tblMessage.nodes('/Root/Response/Message/Response1/Name')t(u)
)r
```

Comment: How far did you get past [`replace value of`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml?view=sql-server-2017)? Please show your code.

Comment: Please see my updated post to see what I have tried. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following sample data:

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
'<Root>
    <Response xmlns:ns1="urn:names:tc:legalxml-message1:schema:xsd:Message-4.0">
        <Message xmlns:ns2="urn:names:tc:legalxml-message2:schema:xsd:Types-4.0">
            <Response1>
                <ns1:Name>REPLACE name1</ns1:Name>
            </Response1>

            <Response2>
                <ns1:Name>REPLACE name2</ns1:Name>
            </Response2>

            <Response3>
                <ns1:Name>REPLACE name3</ns1:Name>
            </Response3>

            <Response4>
                <ns1:Name>REPLACE name4</ns1:Name>
            </Response4>
        </Message>
    </Response>
</Root>';

DECLARE @replaceText VARCHAR(100)  = 'Something New Here';
```

You can use the [XML modify method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml?view=sql-server-2017) to update the values. To do so explicitly by node name you could do this:

```
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/Root/Response/Message/Response4/*:Name/text())[1]
                 with     sql:variable("@replaceText")');
```

In this ^^ example I'm updating the Response4 node. You can also use the node position to update the XML. The example below will update Response1:

```
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/Root/Response/Message//*:Name/text())[1] 
                 with     sql:variable("@replaceText")');
```

To update Response2 you would do change the `[1]` to `[2]` like so:

```
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/Root/Response/Message//*:Name/text())[2] 
                 with     sql:variable("@replaceText")');
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it further with your query. Also, if I have multiple <Response></Response> nodes, can I use the node position as shown in your example.